# Set same properties of different generated dart classes through protobufs

Tags: dart, protocol-buffers

I have multiple protobufs with similar meta properties. (timestamp & meta in below example)

e.g.

```
message Person {
  string name = 1;
  int32 id = 2;
  string email = 3;
  google.protobuf.Timestamp timestamp = 4;
  MetaData meta = 5;
}

message DeviceInfo {
  string name = 1;
  string os = 2;
  int32 version = 3;
  google.protobuf.Timestamp timestamp = 4;
  MetaData meta = 5;
}
```

I am generating dart classes for these protos.

What I am looking for is some kind of dart construct for a common interface through which I can abstract setting these common properties.
e.g.

```
void updateProperties(CommonInterface message) {
 message.timestamp = Timestamp.fromDateTime(DateTime.now());
 message.meta = getMeta();
}
```

I tried multiple ways like using extensions, setters nothing worked.

I don't want to modify the generated dart files as that is not an ideal way to do these.